# Switching between LineChart and AreaChart ruins LineChart series symbol dots

Tags: javafx, charts, missing-symbols

When I load a data series into my LineChart, like linechartVar.getData().addAll(series);

I get the intended result: [add series to linechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1b4U.png)

Than, I load the same series to my AreaChart and at the same time I disable LineChart visibility. So I get this: [add same series to areachart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKsLY.png)

But when I switch back to my LineChart (so disable AreaChart visibility and enable LineChart visibility) I get this: [just called setVisible(false) on areachart and setvisible(true) on linechart (symbol dots are gone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dabQs.png)

Why is that?
Any help is very much appreciated.

Maybe good to know: XYChart series remains the same in the process and it is only added to Area and LineChart only once. But what I noticed is if I recalculate the XYChart series all the time I switch between these two charts the problem won't occur. (But I do not want to recalculate the series over and over again because it is always remains the same. The only thing I wanted to change is the chart "type".)

I do not understand what can cause this behavior.

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: Sharing a `Series` between two charts is the likely culprit. There are properties of the `Series` and `Data` classes that only make sense in the context on a _single_ chart.